# Combing rows of a CSV file with variable length rows based on index value with R

Tags: r

I have some timing data for an experiment, and I would like to group this by an index value in the first column. The index value is how many items appear in that column, as this is measuring the performance of an algorithm scaling it to multiple nodes (the value being the number of nodes and timing for each of them). So the data would look like this

```
+---+----------+---------+--+--------+
| 1 |  3596449 |         |  |        |
| 1 |  3526532 |         |  |        |
| 1 |  3525325 |         |  |        |
| 2 | 3595235  | 2432343 |  |        |
| 3 | 3789900  | 2432343 |  | 345675 |
+---+----------+---------+--+--------+
```

and so on. The file this comes from would be of the form:

```
1,3596449           
1,3526532           
1,3525325           
2,3595235,2432343       
3,3789900,2432343,345675
.
.
.
```

Ideally this would become:

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+-----+
| 1 | 3596449 | 3526532 | 3525325 | ... |
| 2 | 3595235 | 2432343 | ...     |     |
| 3 | 3789900 | 2432343 | 345675  | ... |
+---+---------+---------+---------+-----+
```

Since there are repetitions they would grouped by the index value and combined into a single row. There would be a variable number of data points for each index value.

I've run into issues because data frames only work for data of the same length. I've found that lists are variable length, but I'm not sure how I'd construct this list from reading in the data.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file in with `readLines` and split at the commas using `strsplit`. Since you want a numeric result, you can remove the spaces and convert all the elements to numbers using `gsub` and `as.numeric`.

You can then wrangle the results into the desired format with the `apply` family of functions:

```r
contents <- readLines("my_csv.csv")
my_list  <- strsplit(contents, ",")
my_list  <- lapply(my_list, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", x)))
index    <- sapply(my_list, function(x) x[1])
my_list  <- lapply(my_list, function(x) x[-1])
result   <- lapply(unique(index), function(x) unlist(my_list[index == x]))
```

This gives the following result:

```
result
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 3596449 3526532 3525325
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3595235 2432343
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3789900 2432343  345675
```

Comment: This would summarize all 1-item entries into the first list entry. It might be conceivable that several measurements (different index values) hat 1-item entries. But maybe that's what the OP needed.

Comment: @KarstenW. That's what I assumed the OP meant, but maybe not. I'll update my answer - thank you.

Comment: Elegant solution!

Comment: @AllanCameron The index values are the same as the number of entries in the row, as it is timing for different numbers of network nodes, so the times for 1 node, 2 nodes, etc.